# How do I import a Win32 DLL written in C into Python?

Tags: python, c, winapi

Is this possible? The DLL I need to use is only available as a Win32 DLL written in C, and I haven't programmed in standard C yet.

Comment: It is possible with `ctypes` to some extend if it is a C dll and not C++, and your python is 32-bit, not 64-bit and you're running this on Windows.

Comment: @Antti Win32 covers both 32 and 64 bit Windows API

Comment: @DavidHeffernan hmm well, we do not actually know what the Win32 means here :D

Answer (score 1):

Environment: VS2019 16.6.5

First you need to create a new .dll project.
[image]

[image]

Select the `Windows Desktop Wizard` and the `Dynamic Link Library`.

Then add the code you need to run, I added a simple Message box here.

```
#include <windows.h>


__declspec(dllexport) void fun()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"test", L"test",0);
}
```

Note: The declaration of __declspec(dllexport) is required under windows to indicate that this function is exported by dynamic library.

Generate the solution and place the generated dynamic library under the created python project folder.

Finally, use `ctypes` in Python to call the corresponding dll file.

```
import ctypes
import os 

path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
dllpath = os.path.join(path,"test.dll")

pDll = ctypes.WinDLL(dllpath)

pDll.fun()
```

Operation result:
[image]

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.